# Editing buttons are too poorly contrasted on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

It's difficult to see the icons, other than the 'link' and 'image' ones.  If meta is going to stay this dark, could there be a differently coloured background behind the icons so that they are more visible?

Comment: Whilst that looks quite surreal, I don't have any issues distinguishing the buttons.

Comment: I can distinguish them in a dark room (e.g. at night), but it's the middle of summer here and the sunlight is streaming through all the windows.  Contrast helps.

Comment: @Pureferret We don't design for the well sighted, we design for the many many people without that gift.

Comment: @DampeS8N I wouldn't call myself well sighted, and I agree contrast helps. I was just commenting I could see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have brightened the buttons. The fix will be in the next production build.